# Binary Tree Issue from Input File

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, nodes, delimiter

How can this be fixed to read, sort, and count the binary tree correctly? Also how I could use a delimiter for my overloaded constructor, or as another method, or in my main method?

This is the current Input File I need to use:

```
      A
   /     \
  B        C
   \     /  \
    D   E    F
   /     \
  G       H
 /      /   \
I      J     K
```

The current file that represents the above tree is TreeFile.txt with a sequence that represents the missing nodes:

```
A
B
C
NULL 
D
E
F
NULL
NULL
G
NULL 
NULL
H
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
I
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
J
K
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

But If I use this text file then it will through off the algorithm I use in my code bellow to create and show the tree for the pre-order, in-order, post-order, and level-order, node counting, leaf counting, number of nodes on the left and right. What can be corrected in my code so that the "NULL" is not displayed back and sorting and counting shows correct too?

My Code that takes the input and makes the tree with a sample of pre-order and count left nodes:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class BinaryTree<E> {

private class NodeClass<E> {

    private NodeClass<E> left;
    private NodeClass<E> right;
    private E value;

    public NodeClass(E value) {

        left = null;
        right = null;
        this.value = value;
    }

}

private NodeClass<E> root;

// confusion here
public BinaryTree(Scanner scan) throws Exception {

    NodeClass<E> currentNode = root;
    NodeClass<E> nextNode = null;

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

        String value = (String) scan.nextLine().trim();

        if (value.length() == 0)
            continue;

        if (root == null) {

            root = new NodeClass(value);

        } else {

            currentNode = root;
            nextNode = currentNode;

            while (nextNode != null) {

                if (nextNode.left == null) {

                    insertingLeft(nextNode, (E) value);
                    break;

                } else if (nextNode.right == null) {

                    insertingRight(nextNode, (E) value);
                    break;
                }

                if (nextNode == currentNode) {

                    nextNode = currentNode.left;

                } else if (nextNode == currentNode.left) {

                    nextNode = currentNode.right;

                } else if (nextNode == currentNode.right) {

                    nextNode = currentNode.left.left;
                    currentNode = currentNode.left;

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

public void insertingRight(NodeClass<E> Node, E element) {

    if (Node.right == null) {

        Node.right = new NodeClass<E>(element);

    } else {

        insertingRight(Node.right, element);

    }
}

public void insertingLeft(NodeClass<E> Node, E element) {

    if (Node.left == null) {

        Node.left = new NodeClass<E>(element);

    } else {

        insertingLeft(Node.left, element);

    }
}

public BinaryTree() {

    root = null;

}

public String PreOrder() {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    PreOrder(builder, root);

    return builder.toString();

}

private void PreOrder(StringBuilder builder, NodeClass<E> node) {

    builder.append(" " + node.value.toString());
    if (node.left != null) {

        PreOrder(builder, node.left);

    }

    if (node.right != null) {

        PreOrder(builder, node.right);

    }

}

public int leftCount() {

    return leftCount(root);

}

private int leftCount(NodeClass<E> node) {

    int count = 0;

    if (node.left != null && node.right == null) {

        count++;
        count += leftCount(node.left);

    }

    if (node.right != null) {

        count += leftCount(node.right);

    }

    return count;

}
}
```

My main driver class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testBinaryTree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("TreeFile.txt"));
        BinaryTree<String> bt = new BinaryTree<String>(in);

        System.out.print("Pre Order: " + bt.PreOrder() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Left Count: " + bt.leftCount());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

    }

}

}
```

Which displays back:

```
Pre Order:  A B NULL NULL NULL NULL I NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL J K NULL NULL NULL H NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL D G NULL C E F
Left Count: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "NULL" nodes are displayed because you actually create nodes containing the text "NULL" and don't take them into account when printing the preorder output.

You can either filter those nodes with the text "NULL" when printing the preorder and ignore them (the same as you ignore nodes that are actually `null`).

Or, which I think is better, not insert them from the beginning. This, however, requires you to keep track of the insertion position. I think the easiest way to do that is to put the whole list of nodes in an array first and *then* create the tree from it. There are formulas to calculate the index of the left or right children of a node (2*i+1 for the left son, 2*i+2 for the right son) that help you find the right children.

So first just read all the strings into an array `String[] nodes` and then call `BuildTreeFromArray(0, nodes)` on it to build the tree:

```
NodeClass<E> BuildTreeFromArray(int index, String[] nodes) {
    if (index >= nodes.length) {
        return null;
    } else {
        NodeClass<E> node = new NodeClass<E>(nodes[index]);
        node.left = BuildTreeFromArray(2 * index + 1, nodes);
        node.right = BuildTreeFromArray(2 * index + 2, nodes);
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: would this method be used in the driver or the BinaryTree<E> class? Also would it be better then in the text file to get rid of the "NULL" and just use the letters?

Comment: @rightnight: Since apparently you want to create the tree in the constructor of `BinaryTree`, I would make `BuildTreeFromArray` a private method of `BinaryTree` that you can call from `BinaryTree`'s constructor after reading all the values into the array.

Comment: Oh okay, Also would you know and show how I could use a delimiter for my overloaded constructor or as an another method in BinaryTree<E> with the file I currently have or yours, or using a delimiter in my main method?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you use a better tree representation in the input file.  For example, use a list of triples, each linking a parent to its children. Then order doesn't matter (except make the first node root), and you can ignore all the non-existent nodes:

```
A B C
B - D
D G -
G I -
C E F
E - H
H J K
```

Then it's easy to build the tree using a dictionary of nodes:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TreeBuilder {
  Map<String, Node> valToNode = new HashMap<>();

  static class Node {
    String key;
    Node left, right;

    Node(String key) { this.key = key; }

    void printTree() {
      System.out.print(key);
      if (left != null || right != null) {
        System.out.print("(");
        print(left);
        System.out.print(", ");
        print(right);
        System.out.print(")");
      }
    }

    static void print(Node node) {
      if (node == null) 
        System.out.print("-");
      else 
        node.printTree();
    }
  }

  Node buildTree(String filePath) throws IOException  {
    Node root = null;
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(
        Paths.get(filePath), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
      String[] vals = line.split("\\s+");
      Node parent = lookupOrCreateNode(vals[0]);
      parent.left = lookupOrCreateNode(vals[1]);
      parent.right = lookupOrCreateNode(vals[2]);
      if (root == null) root = parent;
    }
    return root;
  }

  Node lookupOrCreateNode(String key) {
    if ("-".equals(key)) return null;
    Node node = valToNode.get(key);
    if (node == null) {
      node = new Node(key);
      valToNode.put(key, node);
    }
    return node;
  }

  void run() {
    try {
      Node tree = buildTree("src/hacking/data.txt");
      tree.printTree();
      System.out.println();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      System.err.println("input file not found");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TreeBuilder().run();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A(B(-, D(G(I, -), -)), C(E(-, H(J, K)), F))
```

NB: The java is short, but it skips error checking, data hiding, etc.

Comment: Oh okay, Also would you know and show how I could use a delimiter for my overloaded constructor or as an another method in BinaryTree<E> with the file I currently have or yours, or using a delimiter in my main method?